# The radius of Earth is 4 times the radius of the moon. Estimate the acceleration due to gravity on the surface of the moon

Tags: gravity, earth, centripetal-force, moon

I have derived an expression here which just needs the ratio of the densities of the Earth and its moon. My question is how do I go about finding this ratio or is there another way to approach this problem? Only fact I can think of that may be useful is the moon's orbital period being around 27 days but I cannot seem to think of anything that would connect/separate the two densities. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It does say  "estimate". Neglecting the difference in densities may be OK for the exercise, just ask your professor.